# How to convert (Not-One) Hot Encodings to a Column with Multiple Values on the Same Row

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, one-hot-encoding

I basically want to reverse the process posed in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36928852/how-to-convert-a-column-with-multiple-values-into-binary-variables-in-pandas).

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> example_input = pd.DataFrame({"one"   : [0,1,0,1,0], 
                                  "two"   : [0,0,0,0,0],
                                  "three" : [1,1,1,1,0],
                                  "four"  : [1,1,0,0,0]
                                  })
>>> print(example_input)
   one  two  three  four
0    0    0      1     1
1    1    0      1     1
2    0    0      1     0
3    1    0      1     0
4    0    0      0     0
>>> desired_output = pd.DataFrame(["three, four", "one, three, four",
                                   "three", "one, three", ""])
>>> print(desired_output)
                  0
0       three, four
1  one, three, four
2             three
3        one, three
4
```

There are many questions (examples [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59184362/converting-multiple-dummy-variables-into-one-column) & [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63196745/convert-one-hot-encoded-data-frame-columns-into-one-column)) about reversing one-hot encoding, but the answers rely on only one binary class being active per row, while my data can have multiple classes active in the same row.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50607740/reverse-a-get-dummies-encoding-in-pandas) comes close to addressing what I need, but its multiple classes are separated on different rows.  I need my results to be strings joined by a separator (for example ", "), such that the output has the same number of rows as the input.

Using the ideas found in these two questions ([1](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/154550/conditional-concatenation-of-a-pandas-dataframe?newreg=2060e33a1d6d42fcbf2b0f3463cd524d) & [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52173161/getting-a-list-of-indices-where-pandas-boolean-series-is-true)), I was able to come up with a solution, but it requires an ordinary python for loop to iterate through the rows, which I suspect will be slow compared to a solution which entirely uses pandas.

The input dataframe can use actual Boolean values instead of integer encoding if it makes things easier. The output can be a dataframe or a series; I'm eventually going to add the resulting column to a larger dataframe.  I'm also open to using `numpy` if it allows for a better solution, but otherwise I would prefer to stick with `pandas`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do [`DataFrame.dot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dot.html) which is much `faster` than iterating over all the rows in the dataframe:

```
df.dot(df.columns + ', ').str.rstrip(', ')
```

---

```
0         three, four
1    one, three, four
2               three
3          one, three
4                    
dtype: object
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution using a python list comprehension to iterate through each row:

```
import pandas as pd

def reverse_hot_encoding(df, sep=', '):
    df = df.astype(bool)
    l = [sep.join(df.columns[row]) for _, row in df.iterrows()]
    return pd.Series(l)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    example_input = pd.DataFrame({"one"   : [0,1,0,1,0], 
                                  "two"   : [0,0,0,0,0],
                                  "three" : [1,1,1,1,0],
                                  "four"  : [1,1,0,0,0]
                                  })
    print(reverse_hot_encoding(example_input))
```

And here's the output:

```
0         three, four
1    one, three, four
2               three
3          one, three
4                    
dtype: object
```